# Sorting a list using calculation from class definition

Tags: python, sorting

First poster here :)

I am creating a simple golf-style game where several players take turns taking shots. After each shot, the queue of players is reassessed to know who's turn it is next.

The player who is furthest from the target goes next.

The following provides a simplification of the code being used;

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = (0.0, 0.0)

    def distance_to_goal(self, goal_coord):
        ax = ((goal_coord[0] - self.position[0]) ** 2)
        bx = ((goal_coord[1] - self.position[1]) ** 2)
        return math.sqrt(ax + bx)

Player1 = User() #(same for Player2, Player3)
TheGame.turn = [Player1, Player2, Player3]
TheGame.hole.goal_position = (0.0, 40.0)
```

After a player has taken a shot and their position has moved, I want to reorder the list. I tried the following two but didn't work:

```
sorted(TheGame.turn, key = distance_to_goal(TheGame.hole.goal_position))
sorted(TheGame.turn, key = TheGame.turn.distance_to_goal(TheGame.hole.goal_position))
```

I was following this link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/python-sorted/
which indicated I should use a definition as a sorting method.

This works, but I was wondering if there was a method to use sort to refer to a definition with a class?

Thanks!

Comment: check out the priority  queue: https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue. It should be much faster and easy to use.

Comment: Note that `sorted` returns a *new* sequence and does not modify the original. If you want to sort a list in-place, use `list.sort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andy's answer is fine.

Use lambda function is another way.

```
sorted(TheGame.turn, key=lambda user: user.distance_to_goal(TheGame.hole.goal_position))
```

Lambda function is handy when things get more complicated than just a method call.

Comment: Thanks tdihp, this is neat!

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `operator.methodcaller`.

For example:

```
import operator
sorted(TheGame.turn, key=operator.methodcaller('distance_to_goal', TheGame.hole.goal_position))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Andy, I had a play with this and got it working. I also like tdihp's solution as it does not call for an import

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I'm a little late. For the sake of adding to the mix:

```
import math


class User:
    def __init__(self, name='', position=(0.0, 0.0)):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position

    def distance_to_goal(self, goal_coord):
        ax = ((goal_coord[0] - self.position[0]) ** 2)
        bx = ((goal_coord[1] - self.position[1]) ** 2)
        return math.sqrt(ax + bx)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([self.name, self.position])


class Hole:
    def __init__(self):
        self.goal_position = (0.0, 0.0)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.turn = []
        self.hole = Hole()

Player1 = User('Alice', (135.3, 9.0))
Player2 = User('Bob', (7.6, 85.4))
Player3 = User('Clem', (92.4, 43.1))
TheGame = Game()
TheGame.turn = [Player1, Player2, Player3]
TheGame.hole.goal_position = (0.0, 40.0)

print(TheGame.turn)
TheGame.turn.sort(key=lambda user: user.distance_to_goal(TheGame.hole.goal_position))
print([p.distance_to_goal(TheGame.hole.goal_position) for p in TheGame.turn])
print('{0} is closest to the hole!'.format(TheGame.turn[0].name))
```

As [tdhip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000290/tdihp) stated, lambda expressions are bread-and-butter abstractions that make things incredibly easy when you need to yield from an arbitrary function. Also, since you probably want a bit of continuity for your `turn` list, `list.sort()` is used to modify the list in-place. `User.__repr__` is reimplemented for the sake of clarity while testing.